# Let $ M $ is maximal subgroup of $ G $ and $ P_{G}(M)=G $. Is there $ x\in G\setminus M $ that $ G = \langle x \rangle M = M \langle x \rangle $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The permutizer of a subgroup $ H $ of $ G $ is defined to be the subgroup generated by all cyclic subgroups of $ G $ that permute with $ H $,
i.e.  $ \langle x\in G \vert  \langle x \rangle H = H \langle x \rangle \rangle $ 
, denoted by $ P_{G}(H) $.

. A group $ G $ is said to satisfy the maximal permutizer condition if $ P_{G}(M) = G $ for any maximal subgroup $ M $
of $ G $.

Let $ M $ is maximal subgroup of $ G $ and $ P_{G}(M)=G $. Is there $ x\in G\setminus M $ that $ G = \langle x \rangle M = M \langle x \rangle $?

Comment: That seems clear! If $P_G(M)=G$, then there exists $x \in G \setminus M$ with $\langle x \rangle M = M \langle x \rangle$ and they must equal $G$ by maximality of $M$.

Comment: $ M \cap \langle x \rangle = 1 $ ?

Comment: Not necessarily. For example $G=C_4$, $M=C_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I do not understand something , but:

If $x\in G\setminus M$ then (by definition of a maximal subgroup) $G = \langle x \rangle M = M \langle x \rangle$. But $P_{G}(M)=G$ and it means that $x\in P_{G}(M)$. By definition of permutizer of a subgroup $M$ we have $\langle x \rangle M = M \langle x \rangle = G$.

Comment: That's not quite right because $P_G(M)$ is the subgroup generated by $x$ such that $\langle x \rangle M = M \langle x \rangle$, so we do not know that every $x \in G$ has that property. But if $P_G(M)=G$, then there must be some $x \in G \setminus M$ with the property and then we must have $\langle x \rangle M = M \langle x \rangle = G$ for that $x$.